# How to put a hamburger menu in a textbox like google maps?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am new to web app development and I am trying to insert a hamburger-menu icon into an HTML textbox element using angular material drawer. I am hoping to find Something similar to this:
[image]

In angular material.

So far I've this:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container" style="height: 100%;">
  <mat-drawer>
    <app-menu></app-menu>
  </mat-drawer>
  <agm-map id="map" [latitude]="lat" [zoom]="zoom" [longitude]="lng" [zoomControl]="false" [streetViewControl]="false">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
  <mat-form-field id="searchBox">
    <input matInput placeholder="Search something">
  </mat-form-field>

</mat-drawer-container>
```

I'd like the same kind of control as Google's HTML textbox input element that contains a hamburger button, and I want to do this using Angular Material.

I know how to trigger the display of the drawer, but I don't know how to add this hamburger menu here?

Comment: Is it okay if you write custom HTML and CSS?

Comment: @rAMESH kind of my last resort, I wish it works well with the angular theme

Comment: A div which contain a `mat-menu` and a `textbox` using `flex` layout you can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

you can make a flex container to create something like this.

```
<div style="display:flex">
    <button class="menu-button" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
    <input matInput placeholder="search">
  <button class="phone-button" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>microphone</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <div class="rounded-person"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's nice, but then the icon is outside of the textbox? I'm trying to make this looks like "one control". What am I missing?

Comment: You need to open menu on clicking the hamburger right? not focusing the input right? Then I don't think you need to put icon inside input.

Comment: Technically yes, but it's about it looks like. I did put this in a `mat-card`, close to what I need, but I get some weird spacing issues :(

I tried to reproduce it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scgar8

Comment: I think adding a `align-items:center` along with display:flex solve your issue. I didn't used matPrefix because you may need to style the mat-form-field more to get exactly as in google map with no lines and all

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular Material, there's a way to indicate a prefix and a suffix in an input. Using matPrefix and matSuffix should work as you want, you can even add your components.

For example:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <span matPrefix>+1 &nbsp;</span>
    <input type="tel" matInput placeholder="Telephone"> 
    <mat-icon matSuffix>mode_edit</mat-icon>
 </mat-form-field>
```

You can see this in [THIS](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vrvnobdpker?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-prefix-suffix-example.html) StackBlitz. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just have one doubt: Do you think I can bind a click action on the matPrefix?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can bind to the click event and other events as well.